# What Dependency Injection Framework Does ASP.Net Core Use?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-1.0

I've started dabbling in **ASP.Net Core**, and found out that **Dependency Injection** is a First-class Citizen in the ASP.Net Core framework and that it is built-in and ready to use for injecting various services and libraries.

I would like to know ***which Dependency Injection framework*** they are using. Their docs at [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

> ASP.NET Core is designed from the ground up to support and leverage dependency injection. ASP.NET Core applications can leverage built-in framework services by having them injected into methods in the Startup class, and application services can be configured for injection as well

Did they write their own from ground-up? Or are they re-using an existing open source Dependency Injection framework. If yes, which one?

The reason for asking, besides natural curiosity, is also that I want to use the same framework they are using in **ASP.Net Core**, in my `.Net 4.6.1.` **ASP.Net Web API** application.

Because I've found most DI frameworks to be very slow and bloated, even **Unity**.

In contrast, the ASP.Net CORE DI framework seems to be really fast and lean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core is open source, so we can examine this for ourselves. The base repo is at:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

And the ASP.NET Core Repo is at:

https://github.com/aspnet/home

Going to the "DependencyInjection" Repo (https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection) and navigating down in the source we find https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs

Reading through that file it sure *looks* like a DI container. Its fair to say that Microsoft wrote their own, though they also support using existing ones according to the documentation in the Dependency Injection repo.

Comment: They wrote their own, and specifically opted not to give it its own name. It's just "the built-in services container in ASP.NET Core".